# Prove that there exists a countable collection of rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I show that the collection of all the rectangles $[a_1,b_1]\times \cdots \times[a_n,b_n]$, with each $a_i,b_i$ rational, can be arranged in a sequence, that is, that set is countable?
Maybe I could prove it for $n=1$ and then make an induction argument, but i feel that's not the right way. Hints?

Comment: Nothing wrong with an induction argument.  You should definitely start by understanding the $n=1$ case.

Comment: @hardmath however then I cannot see how to relate the case $n=k$ and $n=k+1$

Comment: That's the point where I need help

Answer (score 3):

Let $R_n$ denote the set of rectangles in $\mathbb R^n$ in question. There is a bijection $R_n \times R_1 \xrightarrow{\approx} R_{n+1}$ given by $(A, B) \mapsto A\times B$ where $A \in R_n$ and $B \in R_1$. Once you have this, you just need to prove that $R_1$ is countable and that the product of countable sets is countable, and your proof will be complete by induction.

Comment: One last thing: Is it true that there exists such a bijection?

Comment: Yes, I said what the bijection is in my answer. You have to check for yourself that it really is a bijection though....

Answer (score 1):

If we take an enumeration of the rational numbers, i.e. an injective map $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{N}_{>0}$, we may just consider:

$$ f:[a_1,b_1]\times\ldots\times[a_n,b_n]\to 2^{\varphi(a_1)}\; 3^{\varphi(b_1)}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_{2n-1}^{\varphi(a_n)}\; p_{2n}^{\varphi(b_n)} $$
that injects our set into $\mathbb{N}$.